# C# ActiveX--how to keep the pops-up dialog(windows.Forms.Form) always on top of browser(IE8)

Tags: c#, forms, activex, showdialog

I have write the ActiveX using C# to communicate with the other browser-based system b, it need pops up an dialog in an other thread because of the existing architecture. the current behavior is that the dialog can be hidden behind if i click the browser title. Is it possible to keep the pops-up dialog always on the top of browser(IE8)? Thanks in advance.

```
public int operation()
{   
    ....  
    MyMsgBox myMsgBox = new MyMsgBox(message,title);   
    evt = System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);  
    Thread showDialogThread = new Thread(ShowMsgDialog);  
    ShowDislogThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    showDialogThread.Start(myMsgBox);
    System.Threading.WaitHanle.WaitAll(new System.Threading.WaitHandle[] {evt});  
    ....
}

public void ShowMsgDialog(object requestObj)
{  
    MyMsgBox msgBox = (MyMsgbox)requestObj;  
    msgBox.showDialog();  
    evt.Set();  
}

Class MyMsgBox:Form  
{
    public MyMsgBox(string message, string title)
    {  
        //do initialization....  
    }  
}
```

I have tried to set the TopMost of Form to 'true', then it will be always on the top of all applications. it's not meet the requirement as the pops-up dialog need be only always on the top of browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you want will be possible.

However, you can make a div stretched across all page and set and event on mouse move to call BringToFront on your ActiveX object. That should do the trick.